# VS 2022 17.7.2 slow start up bug?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I just updated VS 2022 from 17.7.1 to 17.7.2 and timing the application load runs from 30-45 seconds.  17.7.1 was very much quicker on the start up than this.

Is anyone else noticing a significant lag when you start visual studio?

I am not referring to loading a solution, just starting the application shows a significant start up lag.

**Follow up**

**8/23/2023:**
I posted this on the developer community at Microsoft: [dev post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-2022-1772-slow-start-up-bug/10447108) . So they are looking into it.  Will post more when I get more feedback.

**9/11/2023:**
Received feedback from Microsoft:
"Thanks for capturing and uploading the recording of the issue! Looking at the trace, VS appears to be searching through a directory which happens to be on a network drive which is making the file IO while opening VS quite slow. We’ve filed an internal bug about this issue to fix this problem."

**10/9/2023**
Here is the latest update
[image]

Thanks

Comment: You might check free disk space and the CPU load.  If something like Windows Update is using too much CPU then start up could be slow.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that too, but my system had been idle with no significant utilization.  No windows update or anything... quiescent for the most part.  I let things sit for a couple minutes and then tried it again with same results.

Comment: Have you tried using devenv.exe /Log (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/log-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022) or something like Sysinternals' Process Monitor?

Comment: Is it slow all the time, or was it just after the upgrade?

Comment: Another thing - "did you try turning it off and then on again?" really does work for Windows sometimes.  A co-worker uses sleep/suspend instead of shutdown and every couple of weeks their PC starts behaving badly.  The fix is to restart.  I've had my own problems fixed by restart when an install had left some tasks on hold until the next reboot.

Comment: It was noticeably slower after the upgrade... and I did try "turning it off and on again".  I put in post in Microsoft's dev forum about this so... shall see.

Comment: I see another update ... 17.7.3 is out today... 3rd update in 3 weeks.... did not see any details on it.  I stand corrected... just took a few minutes for the release details to get publish.... nothing about my issue which is still being looked at.

Comment: @Kixoka got any resolution? i am also facing this issue after updating my Vs 2022. dont see this problem if i rollback to previous version using VS installer but it does not support few required extensions i.e github copilot. My current version v17.6.7 LTS which has this problem,

Comment: @ChUsman - as of 9/28 the matter has been referred to the software engineers for review.  Here's hoping to something good!